# How to add Capture Image to UITableView in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to set the image in UITableView from Image Picker.

My code is like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    CGSize newSizeClient=CGSizeMake(200,200); // I am giving resolution 50*50 , you can change your need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSizeClient);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSizeClient.width, newSizeClient.height)];
    UIImage* newImageClient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    captureimg.image = newImageClient;

    [imageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:captureimg.image];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [Audittable reloadData];
    });

    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((newImageClient), 0.5)];
    OCSSignString = [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30,40,40)];
    UIImage *wonImage = captureimg.image;
    imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [imageView setImage:wonImage];

}
```

In cellforRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      cell.Photobtn.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.Photobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnphotoClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
  cell.CaptureImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The problem I am facing is that it is not getting set according to row like in the Image

[image]

I am capturing image according to tableviewcell

```
-(void)btnphotoClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
     AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = sender.superview.superview;


    imageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<idarray.count; i++) {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
    }

    index=sender.tag;

    if (! [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *deviceNotFoundAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Device" message:@"Camera is not available"
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [deviceNotFoundAlert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraPicker.delegate =self;
        [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing that it is getting over rite.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is idArray here?

Comment: And why yu are replacing the array object?

Comment: @User511 idArray is coming from server.

Comment: Try to add object instead of replacing the object. Or you have set any placeholder images?

Comment: @User511 To add it to tableview.

Comment: @Muju what you want actually first tell me and what imageview you want to set image ?

Comment: Have you set the tag of buttons?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I need to set Image according to tableview cell. I have taken Imageview in custom table view and I am trying to set image in it after capture it.

Comment: Try to replace index with Photobtn.tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your button action you are every time initializing your `imageArray` with empty `UIImage` object. Remove this code from your button action.

```
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<idarray.count; i++) {
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
}
```

You need to initialized your `imageArray` only once with the empty `UIImage` object when you are loading first time your `tableView`.

Comment: @Muju Because you have simply remove the code, What I have told you is you need to remove this code from the button action and put it in place where you are reloading the tableView or where you have set the `idarray`.

Comment: Ok. I Will do that.

Comment: Yes Checking. Actually I am checking it on device from TestFlight That why I need some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
   {
      BookingCell *cell=(BookingCell*)[self.tablebview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.CaptureImage.image = image;
   }

  -(IBAction)buttonclick:(id)sender
   {
      CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
   }
```

Comment: its selected indexpath of button

Comment: Checking Cellforrowatindexpath is correct? I do not need to add Image in Imagearray?

Comment: So I hide this code in cellforrowAtIndexPath cell.CaptureImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: ok you hide the above code and add the below code to imagepickercontroller [self.table reloadrowatindexpath:@[indexpath]]; method